# all links on a page, and how many of these link to the same page again (how can we do that in php)?

Tags: php

I am trying to write a small PHP function that would go through a page (provided a url) and would return the number of links and the number of links that link to the same page. For example, if I provide google.com as a URL it should return how many links are there on google.com and how many links link back to google.com (including of course www.google.com, google.com, google.com/#, etc)

Is that easy to do, and how would I do it?

(this is NOT a homework question so please provide as much help as possible

If you need more information about what I mean with the question just ask me to do provide more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest [SimpleXml](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [DOM](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for this task, but they will choke on invalid markup and unfortunately, the majority of the web is still using invalid markup, [including Google](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.654) you mentioned in your question. You could fetch the HTML from these URLs and [tidy](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) them, but you can also use [SimpleHTML](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
$links = array('inbound' => array(),
               'outbound' => array());

$url  = 'http://www.example.com';
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);    
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->findElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    $linkHost = parse_url($link->href, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $type     = ($linkHost === $host) ? 'inbound' : 'outbound';
    $links[$type][] = $link->href;
}

print_r($links);
```

*Please note that I do not have SimpleHTML installed atm, so the above might not work out of the box. It should point you into the right direction though.*

---

**EDIT**

Oh boy, did I really wrote this? Was I drunk or something? And why did no one complain about it? To correct myself:

DOM handles broken HTML fine if you use the `loadHTML()` method. SimpleXml doesnt. The suggested solution with SimpleHtmlDom will probably work, but IMO SimpleHTMLDom sucks. Better third party libraries can be found in [Best Methods to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662).

Comment: i did install simple html, and implemented the code but it still did not work, is there a reason why is that happening?

Comment: Well, like I said below the code, it *might not work out of the box*, but I won't be able to help if you don't tell me what exactly is not working. Does it show any errors? Did you change the $url? Does it find any links at all? Will there be any links in $links? More details please :)

Answer (score 1):

Load the page content into a variable:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.somesite.com");
```

and do a preg_match() on $html

check php manual for that one.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: While this will work, Regex is not the right tool for *parsing* HTML. Regex is for string pattern matching, not DOM traversal.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

You can use simpleXML to find all the links in a page, and then parse the resulting links with preg_match to see if they match what you're searching for.

Comment: Won't work for invalid HTML. You'd have to use Tidy before SimpleXML or go with SimpleHTML instead.

Comment: He didn't mention invalid HTML =x But i haven't used SimpleHTML before, maybe I should check it out :)

Comment: He mentioned Google. That equals invalid HTML ;)

Answer (score 0):

Combination of a regular expression and a hash I'd say. My PhP sucks but it'd be something like this in Perl

```
my %Counter;
while(my currentLine = <inData>){
if($currentLine = /(www\..+\.+\/)/){
  $Counter{$1}++;
}
}

foreach $thingy (keys %Counter){
 print "There are $Counter{$thingy} links to $thingy in this document\n";
}
```

Comment: And if there's a plain text URL in the page? He wants links. You do not parse HTML with regular expressions.